# Does a c++ compiler do implicit conversions of constants in code?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

Let's assume a declared variable `float Price`. I want to do `Price = Price + 3;`

Is it more efficient (for compiling time) to do `Price = Price + 3.0;`?

My understanding is that constants have types that are detected during lexical analysis, and when the operation is detected during compilation, if the types are not compatible, the compiler will need to do a lossless conversion for the right operands. I don't think there will be an `int`-to-`float` conversion in the assembler code, since the conversion can be done during compiling, but is there an `int`-to-`float` conversion during compiling time (implying more time in processing)?

Comment: technically it would depend on the compiler, one would hope that even with no optimization the compiler would do the conversion at compile time and not run time.  What did you see when you tried it?

Comment: Depends entirely on the compiler, but I'd be surprised at a compiler that didn't do that conversion. You can conveniently test different compilers [here](https://godbolt.org/)

Comment: Technically it is a conversion that has to be done yes, and it could be done runtime if the compiler chose to do that.

Comment: Incidentally you should not be [using float variables to represent money](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency).

Comment: The compiler has to convert every constant in your program from a textual representation to the corresponding internal representation, which is much more expensive than converting between int and  float (or double, which is what you should be using by default). The int->float conversion won't be noticeable.

Comment: `Is it more efficient (for compiling time)` the difference for a single value should be negligible. Anyway testing with initializing [a 100000 static const array](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/MonthlyRightJumpthreading#main.sh) compiles `a[] = {1,2,3...}`  faster then `a[] = { 1.0,2.0,3.0 ...}` on repl with gcc7

Comment: Very cool link @john. Had not tested before, and i am not 100% sure how the assembler notation works, but there doesnt seem to be any difference, except for the data section of the assembler code, as was expected.

Comment: Did `:=` become an assignment operator in C++ while I wasn't looking?  :)

Comment: @Lau For example in this [code](https://godbolt.org/z/aK3zMW) the data `.long   1077936128` is the integer literal `3` converted to a float constant. That number being the binary representation of `3.0f`.

Comment: No one's going to point out that if they wanted a float, they have to type `3.0f`? 3.0 alone is a double, so OP would still be causing a conversion to happen.

Comment: @sweenish I was just about to, but you beat me to it.